# Matching two big SQLITE3 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

**t1:** `f1, f2, f3, f4, rowid_t2, sts`

**t2:** `f1, f2, f3, f4, sts`

with different amounts of records that exceeds 10 millions.

I need to match them using `f1`, `f2` and `f3` of each table as the keys, the relation is
 that one record of t1 can match with one record in t2 or many records of t1 can match with one record in t2, the matching depends on the conditions indicated in the three operations below.

---

I need to perform the next matching operations:

**a)** If `t1.f1 = t2.f1` and `t1.f2 = t2.f2` and `t1.f3 = t2.f3` then I must update the rowid of `t2` into `t1.rowid_t2` and save `t1.sts=1`, `t2.sts=1` in the records matched.

**b)** If `t1.f1 = t2.f1` and `t1.f2 = t2.f2` and `t1.f3 <> t2.f3` then I must update the rowid of `t2` into `rowid_t2` and save `t1.sts=2`, `t2.sts=2` in the records matched.

**c)** If `t1.f1 = t2.f1` and `t1.f2 <> t2.f2` and `t1.f3 <> t2.f3` then I must update the rowid of `T2` into rowid_t2 and save `t1.sts=3`, `t2.sts=3` in the records matched.

---

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I solve the problem using `UPDATE`? If yes, it would be nice if you can show me the solution only for a)
2. How many indexes should I create to optimize the necessary UPDATEs and SELECTs for the three operations?

Many thanks!!

Comment: @Tristan: I reformatted your post, should be easier to read now

Comment: You are right Peter, many thanks!!!

Comment: @Tristan: What exactly do you mean by `t1.one to t1.one and t2.many to t2.one`? What are the ids in the two tables to know which rows to compare? Is `f4` to be ignored?

Comment: I mean that one record of t1 can match with one record in t2 or many records of t1 can match with one record in t2 the matching depends on the conditions indicated in the three operations. I will clarify this. f4 is ignored. Thank your again.

Comment: I'm afried I still don't get the whole picture. Which value do you set for `t2.sts` when one row of `t1` matches by condition **a** and another one by condition **b**?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question but I need to put a "tag" to the records that matched in both tables and the tag is stored in the field "sts". Depending of the type of matching I put 1, or 2 or 3 to sts in both tables, the field rowid_t2 additionally indicates me which records matched. In this way, I can then generate many queries in a fast and flexible way (I have more than 10 millions od records).

Comment: The answer of Hogan looks like what I want as a solution but, it is syntactically not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with `SQLite`, but I gave your problem a try.

As you already said, it is not possible to updated more than one table at once (the [solution provided by Tristran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067069/matching-two-big-sqlite3-tables/2067649#2067649) only works for `MySQL` as far as I know).

First I update `t1` and set `sts=1` for every row (if only a few rows are affected, it might be more efficient to add a `WHERE`-clause to get the relevant rows), and `rowid_t2` to `t2.rowid` where all relevant columns match.

```
UPDATE t1
SET
  sts = 1, 
  rowid_t2 = (
    SELECT rowid FROM t2
    WHERE t2.f1 = t1.f1 AND t2.f2 = t1.f2 AND t2.f3 = t1.f3
  );
```

Then I do the same with `sts=2` and `sts=3` but only where `rowid_t2` has not already been set.

```
UPDATE t1
SET
  sts = 2, 
  rowid_t2 = (
    SELECT rowid FROM t2
    WHERE t2.f1 = t1.f1 AND t2.f2 = t1.f2
  )
WHERE t1.rowid_t2 IS NULL;

UPDATE t1
SET
  sts = 3, 
  rowid_t2 = (
    SELECT rowid FROM t2
    WHERE t2.f1 = t1.f1
  )
WHERE t1.rowid_t2 IS NULL;
```

Then I reset `t1.sts` that have been set to `3` but are not actually valid:

```
UPDATE t1
SET sts = NULL
WHERE rowid_t2 IS NULL;
```

And finally I update `sts` in `t2` to the "lowest" method that matched in `t1`. So if a row in `t2` has one row in `t1` that matches for all criterias, and one that matches only for `f1`, I still set `sts=1`.

```
UPDATE t2
SET sts = (
  SELECT MIN(sts)
  FROM t1
  WHERE t1.rowid_t2 = t2.rowid
)
```

I have not tried with indexes, but I think you should have one for `t2.f1`, `t2.f2` and `t2.f3` for the first three updates (might need separate indexes with `SQLite`, not sure), and another one at `t1.rowid_t2` for the other two updates and for `t1.rowid_t2 IS NULL`.

Try with some representative test data first, to see if the result is as expected and performance is ok.

Good luck :)

Comment: Peter, all your indications are correct and worked in my case as expected. For me, it is a very, very smart and excellent solution, I would never imagine that. Thank you very much and my best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work for a)?

```
update t1,t2
  set t1.rowidt2 = t2.rowid, t1.sts= 1, t2.sts = 1
where t1.f1 = t2.f1 and t1.f2 = t2.f2 and t1.f3 = t2.f3
```

and similar with b) and c)?